# Probability of choosing the basket-i

Tags: probability

Here is the question:

There are N+1 baskets 0,1,2,3,...,N. Where each basket i has i white balls and N-i black balls.

We choose randomly a basket and take out a ball after another with returning.

a)If we know that the first two withdraws we got a black and a white ball (not necessarily by order) what is the probability that we have chosen the basket i?for each i?

b)If we know that the first two withdraws were black balls what is the probability that the third withdraw will be black?

---

Ok,this is an a question in my homework, here is my approach:

a)for i equal 0/N the probability is zero (there is no white/black balls), for any other i the probability is 1/(N-1).
I am not sure about the answer,should we consider that we have picked two different balls, does that effect the probability of which basket we choose?
I know the sum of probabilities for the i-es should equal 1. Which my answer does satisfy.every other answer did not.

b)for b it is the same,will the the first two withdraws effect the third one? I think it does only tell that we have not picked the N-th basket no more.
my answer for b is 1/2.

I would like some hints...
Thank you guys, and sorry english is not my first language.

Comment: Take a look at [Bayes'rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

Comment: I added another approach using Bayes's rule. @saulspatz

Answer (score 1):

another approach:(using bayes`s equation)
let:
A=choosing basket i
B=two two ball withdrawn are blak and white

P(A|B)=$ \frac{P(B|A)*P(A)}{P(B)} $= $ \frac{2*( \frac{i}{N} *  \frac{N-i}{N})*( \frac{1}{N+1}) }{\frac{1}{2}} $ =4 * $\frac{i*(N-i)}{N^3+N^2}$

But the sum of i-es does not equal 1.I think I am wrong somewhere.
@saulspatz

Comment: P(B) is wrong. Basically, if you are in a basket that has a very uneven distribution of black/white balls, you are much more likely to draw 2 balls of the same color than one black/one white. You have to add your enumerators to find the real $P(B)$.

Comment: could P(B)  be ((i/N) *((N-i)/N))? @Ingix

Comment: It it is the sum over all those values (or rather 2 times that, as you correctly wrote in the solution), when $i$ ranges from 0 to N. Note that event B does not mention any basket number, so $P(B)$ cannot contain any $i$.

Comment: ok,so it's the sum from i=0 to N of the following: 2*(i/N)*((N-i)/N)*(1/N). I think it does equal N/6. but what is the mathematic proof for that?or how do I know the sum?

Answer (score 1):

ok,here is my second approach:

a)$\frac{P(B|A)*P(A)}{P(B)} $= $ \frac{2*( \frac{i}{N} *  \frac{N-i}{N})*( \frac{1}{N+1}) }{2*\sum_{i=1}^n a_n(\frac{k}{N}*\frac{N-k}{N})*\frac{1}{N+1}} $ =$ \frac{ \frac{i}{N} *  \frac{N-i}{N}}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_n(\frac{k}{N}*\frac{N-k}{N})} $

I don't know how to get rid of the sigma

b)P(third withdraw is black|first two withdraws are black)=$ \frac{P(the three withdraws are black)}{P(the first two withdraws are black)} $=
$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^N \frac{i^3}{N^3}}{\sum_{i=0}^N \frac{i^2}{N^2}}$=$\sum_{i=0}^N \frac{\frac{i^3}{N}}{\sum_{i=0}^N i^2}$

here too I could'nt get rid of i from the whole equation.any help please?